# Canvas, make an image follow a Bezier curve

Tags: html, animation, canvas, bezier

I want to create an animation with canvas of an image following a semi circle. At first I've tried with a canvas  `arc` but I've found it simpler with a `bezier curve`.

[image]

But now I am facing a problem because since it's not on a circle I can't find a way to make it rotate according to it's position, like a watch pointer. This is my code so far.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var statue = new Image();
statue.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/3TvCH8n/liberty.png';

function getQuadraticBezierXYatPercent(startPt, controlPt, endPt, percent) {
  var x =
    Math.pow(1 - percent, 2) * startPt.x +
    2 * (1 - percent) * percent * controlPt.x +
    Math.pow(percent, 2) * endPt.x;
  var y =
    Math.pow(1 - percent, 2) * startPt.y +
    2 * (1 - percent) * percent * controlPt.y +
    Math.pow(percent, 2) * endPt.y;
  return { x: x, y: y };
}

const startPt = { x: 600, y: 200 };
const controlPt = { x: 300, y: 100 };
const endPt = { x: 0, y: 200 };

var percent = 0;

statue.addEventListener('load', () => {
  animate();
});

function animate() {
  //console.log(percent);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  percent > 1 ? (percent = 0) : (percent += 0.003);
  var point = getQuadraticBezierXYatPercent(startPt, controlPt, endPt, percent);

  ctx.drawImage(
    statue,
    0,
    0,
    statue.width,
    statue.height,
    point.x - 50,
    point.y - 50,
    100,
    100
  );
  //ctx.fillRect(point.x, point.y, 10, 10);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

What is the proper way to do so?

Comment: Can you explain why a bezier curve is easier, because as someone who knows a bit about Bezier curves: a circular arc is _far_ easier than a bezier curve.

Comment: It's because I could get the desired shap I wanted ( a semi-circle slightly flattened) and the image position at a certain time with a simple function with no trigonometry involved .

Comment: at the expense of non-linear path motion, and calculus instead of trig, which is an arbitrary difference (the quadratic computation is more complex _and_ more expensive than arc maths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same function to get another point slightly before the current one on the curve, then use `Math.atan2` to get the angle between the two points.

Then, you'll need to use `ctx.translate()` and `ctx.rotate()` to mutate the transformation matrix instead of setting the position in the `.drawImage()` call. (The `.setTransform()` call at the start of the animation method resets the matrix for each frame.)

I also added an "onion skin" effect here, so the motion is better seen.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var statue = new Image();
statue.src = "https://i.ibb.co/3TvCH8n/liberty.png";

function getQuadraticBezierXYatPercent(startPt, controlPt, endPt, percent) {
  var x =
    Math.pow(1 - percent, 2) * startPt.x +
    2 * (1 - percent) * percent * controlPt.x +
    Math.pow(percent, 2) * endPt.x;
  var y =
    Math.pow(1 - percent, 2) * startPt.y +
    2 * (1 - percent) * percent * controlPt.y +
    Math.pow(percent, 2) * endPt.y;
  return { x: x, y: y };
}

const startPt = { x: 600, y: 200 };
const controlPt = { x: 300, y: 100 };
const endPt = { x: 0, y: 200 };

var percent = 0;

statue.addEventListener("load", () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  animate();
});

function animate() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  // "Onion skin" effect so the last frame is slightly retained to better show the motion.
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  
  percent = (percent + 0.003) % 1;
  
  var point = getQuadraticBezierXYatPercent(startPt, controlPt, endPt, percent);
  var lastPoint = getQuadraticBezierXYatPercent(startPt, controlPt, endPt, percent - 0.003);
  var angle = Math.atan2(lastPoint.y - point.y, lastPoint.x - point.x);
  
  // Debug pointer line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
  ctx.lineTo(point.x + Math.cos(angle) * 50, point.y + Math.sin(angle) * 50);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  // Actual drawing
  ctx.translate(point.x, point.y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(statue, 0, 0, statue.width, statue.height, -50, -50, 100, 100);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Comment: Not computing anything and just letting the canvas do all the heavy lifting by telling it how to translate()/rotate() is even nicer though: no maths required at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a circle anyway, it's *way* easier, but rather than trying to place things at coordinates, do it the other way around: set the *coordinate system* to the correct offset and angle, so that you can then draw the same thing at the same coordinate.

We observe that we're dealing with a circular path that has (300,600) as origin, with a radius of 500, and a start angle (in radians) of 0.9272951769 and an end angle (in radians) of 2.21429922, so we can shift our coordinate system such that (0,0) is "really" (300,600), and then as we rotate the coordinate system about that new (0,0) by any angle, all we need to do is draw things at (radius,0)

Because the coordinate system is doing the rotating for us, we don't need to actually compute *any* points. We already know where we want things to be: a distance `radius` away from the origin.

```js
cvs.width = 600;
cvs.height = 200;
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
const statue = new Image();
statue.onload = () => animate();
statue.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/3TvCH8n/liberty.png';
const sWidth = sHeight = 80;

// circle values matching your path:
const origin = {x: 300, y: 600 };
const radius = 500;
const start = 0.9272951769;
const end = 2.21429922;

// animation values
let step = 0;
const totalSteps = 120;
const stepSize = (end - start)/totalSteps;

// And our drawing function
function animate() {
  ctx.resetTransform();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);

  if (step === totalSteps) step = 0;
  const angle = start + step++ * stepSize;

  // first, change the coordinate system so that we don't need
  // to compute *anything* to draw it in the right place:
  ctx.translate(origin.x, origin.y);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  
  // Then we draw the debug line:
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(radius, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  // And then we draw the image. However, the image is upright
  // when (radius,0) lines up with the x-axis, which means it's
  // actually going to look rotated compared to our line. So:
  // again, we update the coordinate system to do the work for us.
  // we update it so that (radius,0) becomes (0,0), we then rotate
  // it a quarter turn, and then we draw our image at (0,0).
  ctx.translate(radius, 0);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);

  // of course, (0,0) is the image's top-left corner, so if we
  // want to center it, we can do one more translation:
  ctx.translate(-sWidth/2, -sHeight/2);
  ctx.drawImage(statue, 0, 0, sWidth, sHeight);

  // and move on to the next frame
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

This way, we're not writing *any* code for computing "where we need to draw things, with what orientation", instead we're only using fixed points, and letting the canvas2d context take care of all the translations/rotations.

And a little know fact: all browser make HTML elements with an `id` attribute available to JS using that id as its variable name. So in this case we have a `<canvas id="cvs">`, which means that on the JS side there is a variable called `cvs` that points to our canvas element.

Comment: Hmm, IIRC a quadratic Bezier path can't precisely represent a circle?

Comment: Correct, but the original post started with them wanting a semi-circle, but then using a quadratic Bezier "because it was simpler", which it's just not, it instead makes things _much_ harder =)

Comment: I figured OP had some other reason to switch to a Bezier curve too. But yeah, tracing a circle arc would be very simple with a bit of trigonometry...

Comment: I ended up using this solution after I finished to fully understand it (cost me a lot more than the bezier solution...). But since @AKX answered to the problem I had, I still have to leave it as "accepted answer".

Comment: you may wish to switch the accepted answer then, but both answers rely on the same concept: change the coordinate system and draw things "in place" rather than keeping the coordinate system in place and changing where things get drawn =)